# I want to create image slider by using mouse drag without using extra plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create image slider by using mouse drag without using extra plugins. Is there any mathematical formula to be used in jQuery to get this with help of following functions?

```
$(".cont").on("mousestart",function() {  
     $(".cont").on("mouseend",function() {
     });
});
```

I don't want external plugins

Comment: Yes. But post minimal code which you have tried. And Don't forgot to accept any of the answer which solve your issue from your previous question by right click symbol. Else give comment if it not solve your issue.

Comment: or you can create snippet or fiddle for code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example of changing image on click event. you can also bind any other event if require.

```js
$(function () {
    var transition_speed = 300;
    var simple_slideshow = $("#exampleSlider"),
        listItems = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,i = 0;
    changeList = function () {
    listItems.eq(i)
      .fadeOut(transition_speed,function () {
        i += 1;
        if (i === listLen) {
          i = 0;
        }  
        listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
      });
    };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    $('#exampleSlider').on('click', function () {
        changeList(); // Do this once immediately
    })
});
```

```css
img {
    width: 100%:
}
#exampleSlider {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width:500px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="exampleSlider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x260" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x270" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x280" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but u hav any example by changing image with help of mouse drag

Comment: yes, it worked,but when I move the mouse out of div its slide changes without clicking the div